# Edit access by checking the field?

Tags: drupal, role

Is it possible to check the privileges for a particular field? For example, I have a field in the material field_access associated with the user who accepts an ID of the user. How to check access to edit the material through it? Currently editing is possible only if the user specified in the authors. (google translate. sry for that)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Field permissions" module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions